# Matlab how to open file in excel put into array and convert numbers to units of measurement

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file to open matlab and put into an array of cells - then take the numbers in the cells and convert a few measurements. how do i do this

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking into the two functions `xlsread` and `xlswrite`  These both handle input (from an .xls or .xlsx) file to matlab and output from matlab to an excel file, respectively.  If you're looking to do something different than that, please elaborate a bit more than what you've posted.